# Message level security for web application

Tags: angularjs, security, authentication, web-applications, https

I have a HTML5, AngularJS application in which I authenticate user based on windows authentication. This works fine.

I have a connect option in the application which allows user to connect to some other data source. To connect I prompt user for user name & password which is sent to a service for authentication. I am using AngularJS $http to invoke the service and pass the credentials as post parameters.

The problem is I am able to see the credentials in clear text using fiddler. I switched to HTTPS/SSL but still it is visible in fiddler. Following are my observations & queries

1. HTTPS/SSL only ensures transport level security, I would like to know whether I should bother about message level security in web application if transport level security is already in place (using HTTPS).
2. How I would ensure message level security in JavaScript/Angular.
3. Interestingly I used fiddler with gmail and hotmail as well. When I enter credentials on these sites fiddler does not captures it. Any idea how does it happen on these sites? They must be sending credentials for authentication.

Atul Sureka